# How to do decompression to a compressed file read from standard input(stdin) in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, compression

everyone.
I need to write a script which takes a argument test.xxx from stdin just like this:

```
./script < test.xxx
```

test.xxx is compressed by gzip command, and I wanna use gunzip and pax to expand archive to a directory. The script is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do             #here try to catch input file
    echo $line >> /tmp/tmpfile
done
gunzip < /tmp/tmpfile | pax -r /tmp
...
```

This read form seems only work for regular file rather than compression file, and I wonder how to store the compression file read from stdin so that ->

I can execute "gunzip < /tmp/tmpfile | pax -r /tmp" and expand files to /tmp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `zcat`, this will un-gzip from the standard input.

```
#!/bin/sh
zcat | pax -r /tmp
...
```

Comment: But if I write " compress_script < file | decompress_script > /tmp/output ", the compress_script takes file from stdin and output to stdout. The shell will throw "zcat: unknown compression format". Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Regarding that error: are you sure that your file is a gzip-compressed file?  Or is it plain text?  (If it's plain text, `zcat` will choke on it.)  Or is it some other kind of file entirely?  (The `file` command can help you here - run `man file` for more info.)  Or is the file corrupt?  (In your original script you were using the shell `read` builtin to read a binary compressed file "line-by-line" like a text file - a major no-no!)

Comment: In the end of compress_script, it compresses plain text files in /tmp to stdout: " find /tmp -type f -print | pax -w | gzip ", and in the decompress_script, it decompress and store: " gunzip | pax -r /tmp2 "